# EF Bug to add Tables

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I Can't find two tables to add on my Diagram.
This is a bug or a feature?

[image]

[image]

**----------------------UPDATE-------------------------------**

I found the problem. 
i don't know why, when I remove the tables of diagram these tables still there. Them it is a bug on VS.

[image]

Comment: I believe EF requires a primary key for an object to show up in the model diagram.

Comment: I tried with a KEY and I removed to try again.

Comment: Not quite (it just infers a primary key if one doesn't exist). I believe this may be caused by those tables (or atleast RelComanyContact) being comprised of references only. Generally, it will convert a table like that to a Navigation Property (or properties) instead. Is there a specific reason for the table? You could put idContact in Company and idCompany in Contact and get rid of that table all together.

Comment: But my other Relations tables I can see when I trying add. After these tables are Logical and exists only inside the other tables. But now, I can add 2 tables. Contact and RelCompanyContact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has worked out that `RelCompanyContact` is a many-to-many join table between `Company` and `Contact`, and thus isn't going to materialize it. If you add Company and Contact to your EF designer you will find there's going to be a many-to-many join with a `Company.Contacts` property and `Contact.Companies` property by default.

If your join table doesn't follow the rules then it doesn't do this magic for you (look at your other many-to-many join tables, that have composite primary keys using both IDs).

Comment: My questions is not how it works with relations. was why the tables doesn't show to me. Thank for your help, I found the problem and I updated the question.

Comment: Based on your update, the issue is that when you removed them previously, you didn't read the dialog that popped up, and just clicked "No". It was offering to remove them from there as well.